# Как вывести все буквы, которые входят в наибольшее количество слов строки?

Tags: excel, vba

Как решить задачу на VBA, в ячейке задана строка к примеру "Hello World!" нужно вывести все буквы, которые входят в наибольшее количество слов строки.

Пока что остановился на этапе поиска совпадений букв в разных словах

```
Public Function CountChar(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
'Dim str1 As String
'Dim str2 As String
'str1 = Range("A1").Value
'str2 = " "
k = 0
For i = 1 To Len(str1)
If StrComp(Mid(str1, i, 1), str2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
k = k + 1
End If
Next
CountChar = k
End Function
Sub sovpad()
Dim lsRow&, i&, j&, arr, s$
Dim k As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim g As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim st As String
Dim RusAlpha As Variant
Dim EngAlpha As Variant
Dim iLastRow As Long
x = 2
EngAlpha = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
RusAlpha = Array("à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "¸", "æ", "ç", "è", "é", "ê", "ë", "ì", "í", "î", "ï", "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ö", "÷", "ø", "ù", "ú", "û", "ü", "ý", "þ", "ÿ")
lsRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
    For i = 1 To lsRow
        arr = Split(Cells(i, 1), " ")
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            s = arr(j)
            If Cells(i, 2) Like s Then Cells(i, 4) = "": Exit For Else: Cells(i, 4) = ""
            For k = 0 To 32
                st = RusAlpha(k)
                count = CountChar(s, st)
                If (count > 0) Then
                    Range("A" & x).Value = st
                    Range("B" & x).Value = CountChar(s, st)
                    'MsgBox st & CountChar(s, st)
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            Next k
            For z = 0 To 25
                st = EngAlpha(z)
                count = CountChar(s, st)
                If (count > 0) Then
                    Range("A" & x).Value = st
                    Range("B" & x).Value = CountChar(s, st)
                    'MsgBox st & CountChar(s, st)
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            Next z
            Range("A" & x).Value = " "
            Range("B" & x).Value = " "
        Next j
    Next i
iLastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox iLastRow
For g = 2 To iLastRow
    For h = 2 To iLastRow
        If (Range("A" & g).Value = Range("A" & h)) Then
            'MsgBox Range("A" & g).Value
        End If
'MsgBox g
    Next h
Next g
End Sub
```

Comment: Могу посоветовать в функции `CountChar` использовать не цикл по каждой букве строки, а `InStr`, ведь как следует из задания, важно только наличие буквы в слове, а не сколько раз она в нём встречается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас код не совпадает с заданием. В задании указано, что текст в определённой ячейке. А в коде Вы делаете цикл по `CurrentRegion`, следовательно текст может быть не только в первой ячейке. А с другой стороны в первой же итерации этого цикла Вы строкой `Range("A" & x).value = st` перезаписываете то, что там могло быть.

Я бы переделал Ваш код:

1. Если строк действительно несколько, то первым делом объединил бы их в одну строковую переменную, а затем её бы уже разделил в массив.

   ```
   Dim text As String
   text = ""
   For i = 1 to Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
       text = text & " " & Cells(i, 1).Value
   Next i
   arr = Split(text, " ")
   ```
2. Из двух массивов букв сделайте лучше один.
3. Для каждой буквы: записываете её в первый столбец и в цикле выполняете `InStr` в каждом слове. Если результат не `NULL` и больше 0, то значение второго столбца увеличиваете на 1. Таким образом Вы получите значение, во скольких словах данная буква встречается.

   ```
   For i = LBound(Letters) To UBound(Letters)
       st = Letters(i)
       Range("A" & x).Value = st
       Range("B" & x).Value = 0
       For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
           If InStr(1, arr, st, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
               Range("B" & x).Value = Range("B" & x).Value + 1
           End If
       Next j
   Next i
   ```
4. Отсортируйте заполненный диапазон по второму столбцу по убыванию.

Ну или можно в 3-4 пункте записывать значения не на лист, а в двумерный массив, который потом отсортировать.